# Detect the active link item in Handlebars by comparing it with the page URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

when setting up my menu with handlebars I want to detect the active menu item that matches the current URL.

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a>1.1</a>
<br>
<a class="active">1.2</a>
<br>
<a>1.3</a>
```

because currently I return my menu as a object and pass it to the template renderer. I think I have to solve this by client code. This code snippet works fine

```
const setActiveSidebarLink = () => {
    const currentPagePath = window.location.pathname;
    const sidebarLinks = $(".sidebarLink");
    const activeSidebarLink = $(".sidebarLink[href$='" + currentPagePath + "']")[0];

// do something with activeSidebarLink
}
```

Can I check this with handlebars?